# Buttons aligns right in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, semantic-ui

I'm trying to have my buttons vertically centered but horizontally aligned to the right. It is important that it is responsive! It works in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3fLg.png) but not in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqvWQ.png).
Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enLcogy2/4/

[I had a similar problem once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969977/css-menu-not-positioned-to-the-right-side), but this time `position` doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `right` and `left` for `justify-content` works currently only in firefox so it is better to use `flex-end`

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I'll vote you up as soon as I have enough reputation :) thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, this is what I have on chrome, seems to work.

[IMG Fiddle Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubDLr.png)